# class level or struct level method in swift like static method in Java?

Tags: swift

Is there a way to add method at class level or struct level in swift?

```
struct Card {
    var rank: Rank
    var suit: Suit
    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "The \(rank.simpleDescription()) of \(suit.simpleDescription())"
    }
}
```

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

Now if you wanted to add a method that creates a full deck of cards, what would be the best way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 91):

To add a type-level method in a class, add the `class` keyword before the `func` declaration:

```
class Dealer {
    func deal() -> Card { ... }
    class func sharedDealer() -> Dealer { ... }
}
```

To add a type-level method in a struct or enum, add the `static` keyword before the `func` declaration:

```
struct Card {
    // ...
    static func fullDeck() -> Card[] { ... }
}
```

Both are generally equivalent to static methods in Java or class methods (declared with a +) in Objective-C, but the keyword changes based on whether you're in a class or struct or enum. See [Type Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-XID_307) in *The Swift Programming Language* book.

Comment: This has been updated in 6.3, for what it's worth: http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.3_beta/Xcode_6.3_beta_Release_Notes.pdf Cheers

Comment: Classes have both "static" and "class" funcs. See following answer for explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/29636742/2774520

Answer (score 31):

In Struct:

```
struct MyStruct {
    static func something() {
        println("Something")
    }
}
```

Called via:

```
MyStruct.something()
```

In Class

```
class MyClass {
    class func someMethod() {
        println("Some Method")
    }
}
```

called via:

```
MyClass.someMethod()
```

Comment: @IrshadQureshi - there's many differences, the most important in my mind is that structs are ValueType and classes are ReferenceType

Comment: @IrshadQureshi And structs can't be extended like classes

Comment: subclasses can override class func's which is not possible with static methods.

Answer (score 8):

p 353

```
class SomeClass {
    class func someTypeMethod() {
        // type method implementation goes here
    }
}
SomeClass.someTypeMethod()
```

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l