# creating a class with a function to configure views look - swift

Tags: ios, swift

I created this class to configure every view controller to avoid redundancy inside viewdidload().

```
class Configuration: UIViewController  {

    func setNavigationTheme(#backgroundImage: String, dashboardImage: String) {

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: dashboardImage), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let bgImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: backgroundImage)!
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: bgImage)

    }

}
```

inside viewDidLoad()

```
var configure = Configuration()
configure.setNavigationTheme(backgroundImage: "Background", dashboardImage: "Dashboard")
```

When I call the function, it does not change anything, am I doing it wrong or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend your view controller with your Configuration class.

```
    class MyViewController: Configuration {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //Don't initialize new Configuration class.
        setNavigationTheme(backgroundImage: "Background", dashboardImage: "Dashboard")

    }
}
```

Your Configuration class:

```
class Configuration: UITableViewController  {

    func setNavigationTheme(#backgroundImage: String, dashboardImage: String) {

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: dashboardImage), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let bgImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: backgroundImage)!
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: bgImage)

    }

}
```

Comment: how do I fit that here "class ActivityTableViewController: UITableViewController " should I instead create a protocol?

Comment: Just change your Configuration class with "class Configuration: UITableViewController {...)" instead of "class Configuration: UIViewController  {...}" I edited my answer

Comment: it worked! but how am I going to apply this to a UIViewController and other controllers?

Comment: I believe there's a better way to do this

Comment: Create own helper class with static function and pass backgroundImage, dashboardImage and navigationController. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107833/class-level-or-struct-level-method-in-swift-like-static-method-in-java)