# Whats a difference between static function and non Static in Swift?

Tags: swift, oop

I have model and in this model contains a function to SUM 1 + 1
Why should I have to make this function non-static?

The difference is an only instantiable class or not?

Calling static function in Controller

```
Model.sumFunction()
```

Calling non-static function in Controller

```
let model = Model()
model.sumFunction
```

What's a real difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636633/static-vs-class-functions-variables-in-swift-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `SubClass` of your model class can override `non static` function whether is `class` or `instance`. but `SubClass` can't override `static` function.

And the reason behind that is `static` get one time memory allocation and remains in memory until class remains in memory!

Comment: depends on need. generally we are not using static functions. If we need something that not need to allocate memory everytime whatever the reason then we should use static. For, example we generally declare `static identifier`  in `cellforrowatindexpath` method becoz identifier will always be same and this method call too many time so make it static is better!

Comment: Thanks! But if I do everything in static class, what is the problem that I will have in the future?

Comment: Refer [https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html)