# is it possible to declare Computed property and Observers with class Label type?

Tags: swift

I am new in swift anyone help me to understand

what is the purpose ?  I should be used `class` label type !

is it possible to declare   `Computed` property and `Observers`  with `class Label` type ?

both ,either or neither ?

thank you

Comment: Did you put class var name: String?

Comment: give down vote . but please guide me what is the problem here ?  what should i do ?

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636633/static-vs-class-functions-variables-in-swift-classes/37770112#37770112

Answer (score 3):

**Type Properties** can be created using either `static` or `class` keyword

1. **Computed properties** can be created using `class` as well as `static`  keyword.
2. **Property observers** are not allowed using `class` keyword. They can only be used with `static`.

**Example**:

```
class First
{
    class var x : Int{
        return 3
    }

    static var y : Int{
        return 2
    }

//    error: class stored properties not supported in classes
//    class var z = 10 {
//        willSet{
//            print(newValue)
//        }
//    }

    static var w = 30 {
        willSet{
            print(newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is  it possible to Property observers without initialization?

Comment: Property observers can only be used with stored properties. So you need to initialize the property to some value before you start observing it for changes.

Answer (score 0):

### Class Computed Property

You can declare a class computed property

```
class Foo {
    class var p0: String { return "p0" }
}
```

### <s>Class</s> Static Stored property

It is somehow possible but you need to use the `static` keyword

```
class Foo {
    static var p0: String = "p0" {
        didSet {
            print("Did set p0")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stored property possible to without initialisation ?

Comment: Lazy stored properties can be created without initialization before the object is created. But still you have to give it some value/expression that can be computed when it is first used. For normal stored properties you need to initialize them either with default values or in init()